# how can we create a jar file for our program?

Tags: java, netbeans

I work with netbeans,how can I create a jar file for my program?
please help me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans: Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#Exercise_1) (Main Exercise: Creating and Distributing Executable JAR Files)

Comment: I can not open this link would you please explain it yourself?
sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built in project templates NetBeans builds jar files automatically. Just select "Build" from the context menu (right-click your project node) and the jar file will be created inside a "dist" directory in project folder.